# Custom simpltest does not run successfully

Tags: 7, testing

I have written an automated test to create a node of a specific content type.

Here is the code:

```
class GlueTestingBuySystemTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  protected $privileged_user;

  public static function getInfo() {
    return array(
      'name' => 'Buying system',
      'description' => 'Buying system test',
      'group' => 'GLUE',
    );
  }

  public function setUp() {
    $this->profile = 'testing';
    // Enable any modules required for the test. This should be an array of
    // module names.
    parent::setUp(array('glue_testing'));

    // Create and log in our privileged user.
    $this->privileged_user = $this->drupalCreateUser(array(
      'administer nodes',
      ));
    $this->drupalLogin($this->privileged_user);
  }

  public function testBuyingSystem() {
    $edit = array();
    $edit['title'] = $this->randomName(8);
    $this->drupalPost('node/add/test', $edit, t('Save'));
    $this->assertText(t('Test Node Type @title has been created.', array('@title' => $edit['title'])));
  }

}
```

It does appear in the group "GLUE" but when I run the test it gives me the errors:

```
Failed to set field title to lLzjWnd0
Found the Save button
Found the requested form fields at node/add/test
"Testing Node Type lLzjWnd0 has been created." found
```

And does not create any node nor created the user.
Any one who have idea that what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

afaik there's any content-type in the testing site. You need to create it first. For example date module creates one in [DateFieldBasic::setUp](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21date%21tests%21date_field.test/function/DateFieldBasic%3A%3AsetUp/7) (surely there're more examples in core, but I've got that one at hand).

Comment: `$this->profile="testing"`. It means the simpletest will use a testing site? If yes then how will I enforce  my test case to use my current site?

Comment: I've never used $this->profile. Not sure if this means anything. You can't use your current site for testing. Simpletest installs testing site isolated from your current site. See documentation: https://www.drupal.org/node/394888